# Scanner and nextInt()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Guys I'm seeing alot of Q/A in and around what I'm looking for but not exactly what I'm looking for.

The Situation: I am reading in suduko puzzles from a file.. first I run them through a verify() method in which I call next and and check each of (anticipated) 81 numbers to make sure they are between 1 and 9. Then I compare my running count to 81. As long as count == 81, I know the puzzle atleast has the ability to be solved.. when I attempt to re-access the the stream using nextInt() [this time to assign each in into the suduko array] the program crashes reporting NoSuchElement.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:838)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
at edu.dccc.dpr212.suduko.SudokuPuzzle.<init>(SudokuPuzzle.java:31)
at edu.dccc.dpr212.suduko.Sudoku.main(Sudoku.java:30)
```

Some people say that trying to access a closed stream causes this error, but I never close the stream. I open the file in main, and pass it as an argument to the constructor, then the constructor passess it to the verify(Scanner input)method which calls nextInt() on the scanner and then the constructor accesses it again [using nextInt()] to assign the numbers to the puzzle.

I think what is happening is the verify method uses up the nextInt method and it never resets.. is this possible? How could I get around this? Am I passing the Scanner around too much?

code is below:

```
public SudokuPuzzle(Scanner input)
{

    //verify puzzle FORMAT is correct 
    if (verifyPuzzle(input)) {
        //Load Numbers Into Puzzle Array
        for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++){
            for (int column = 0; column < 9; column++) {
                grid[row][column] = input.nextInt();        
            }
        }       
    }
}

/**Verify Puzzle Is Valid Before Attempting To Solve
 * 
 * @param input (file)
 * @return true if puzzle is valid
 */
public boolean verifyPuzzle(Scanner input) {
    boolean isVerified = false;
    int temp = 0, count = 0;

    while (!input.hasNextInt() == false) {
        temp = input.nextInt();

        // Are Numbers Within Range (1 - 9)?
        if (temp > 9 || temp < 0)
        {
            System.out.println ("Puzzle Is Invalid. " + temp + " is an invalid number in Suduko.");
            count--; //Ensures that last number will not generate valid puzzle count and return puzzle as valid
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }

    //Are There Enough Numbers?
    if (count != 81)
        System.out.println ("Puzzle Is Invalid. Does Not Contain 81 Numbers"); 
    else
        isVerified = true;

    return isVerified;
}
```

Comment: Your verifyPuzzle method gobbles up all the input, so when you pop back out into the calling method theirs nothing left to be processed in the for loops. You will need to rethink your design - one option would be to incorporate the verification into the building process. Another would be to use a new Scanner for the build.

Comment: @Perception whats the fix?

Comment: @MBarnett - I expanded the comment.

Comment: close the scanner and reopen it

Comment: @Smit thats the exclusionary conditions.. if any number in the puzzle is less that 0 or bigger than 9 i want it to throw the puzzle out

Comment: @Perception thanks! there's not reset in java for this kind of thing? I checked the API but didn't understand the reset() method.

Comment: @MBarnett - some Java IO classes have the capability to rewind, unfortunately Scanner is not one of them. The reset method is used to managed the delimiter.